# Can i read CSV files faster if i change anything? Is readlines the best way to go?

Tags: c#, performance, csv, readfile

Edit: Thank you @Progressive for the help, I was in a hurry writing and for once was in need of a spell check ;)
I removed the DB connection and that was the problem with performance. I will look into the code and see if there's anything I can do to speed up that part of the code. Thank you all for the insights!

I'm trying to read about 50-100 CSV files with between 5000-20000 rows. It takes a lot of time, my question is if my code is possible to execute faster perhaps with streamread instead or any other method?
The text in the file is built like this
123456789;ROBERT;1;2019-04-26;01;10;HOUR;PARIS
Where the first segment is id, second name, third group, fourth date, fifth hour, sixth value and seventh is "hour" to determine what format it is, eight cities, Each row is another hour.

The background is that I'm reading files and inserting them into SQL. SQL connection is already made btw.

I have tried using File.ReadAllLines, but it was slower. 
I moved the savechanges in DB to the outer foreach loop to get some performance. It did a little. Still, it takes about 20 minutes to read a 10000-row csv file (600 KB).
I also tried making a class with the parameters I'm setting, didn't increase the performance.

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "**.csv");

foreach (string s in filePaths)
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(s).Skip(1);

    foreach (var csvLine in lines)

    {
        if (csvLine.Contains(";;;;;"))
        {
            break;
        }

        List<string> values = new List<string>(csvLine.Split(';'));


        string id = values[0];
        string date = values[3];
        var timestart = values[4];

        //Convert "01" to 01:00
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(timestart);
        TimeSpan hourTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(result);
        string fromTimeString = result.ToString("HH");

        //Set timestart and time end
        DateTime resultDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
        DateTime timeStart = resultDate.Add(hourTime).AddHours(-2);
        DateTime timeEnd = timeStart.AddHours(1);


        var year = timeStart.Year;
        var month = timeStart.Month;
        var day = timeStart.Day;
        var hour = timeStart.Hour;

        //set id
        string dataId = id.ToString();

        //set sum
        double sumValue = double.Parse(values[4]) * 10;
        /

        var hourValue = myDB.HourValues.Where(w => w.streamID == dataId && w.TimeStart == timeStart).FirstOrDefault();

        if (hourValue == null)
        {
            hourValue = new HourValues
            {
                streamID = dataId,
                TimeStart = timeStart,
                TimeEnd = timeEnd,
                YearInt = year,
                MonthInt = month,
                DayInt = day,
                HourInt = hour,
                ResultTime = DateTime.Now,
                SumValue = (decimal)sumValue,


            };
            myDB.HourValues.Add(hourValue);
        }
        else 
        {
            hourValue.OriginalSum = hourValue.OriginalSum ?? hourValue.SumValue;
            hourValue.ResultTime = DateTime.Now;
            hourValue.SumValue = (decimal)sumValue;
        }
    }

    myDB.SaveChanges();
}
```

I would like to see if I can read the files faster somehow. And appreciate any help I can get or insight into the code.

Comment: Use a profiler. Where it tells you the "hot spots" are, work to improve those parts of the code. Repeat.

Comment: Consider posting your full code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, if your code is otherwise working.

Comment: Define "slow". Also, use a profiler to see *what* specifically is slow.

Comment: Would it be more correct to use `csvLine.StartsWith(";;;;;")`, or even `csvLine == ";;;;;"`?

Comment: I'd guess anything "slow" that's happening is probably at the point you're interacting with `myDB` -- rather than reading the flat file.

Comment: My guess is 99% of the time is in the line `var hourValue = myDB.HourValues....`.

Comment: A quick way to see which half of the code is being slow would be to comment out the `myDB.SaveChanges();` line. If it speeds up drastically, that's where you need to look instead.

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr if you are talking about the built in one in VS then it's saying i'm using 142MB ram and 30-50% CPU atm, but thats pending a lot up and down, not over 50% though.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that line ";;;;" is to break the loop if it encounters a file with ;;;; which all files have at the end of them, without that i got an exception and code would stop everytime. But thanks for noticing.

Comment: Try running code without saving to database and compare times.  See how much time is spend just reading.  The long time may be the writing to the database.

Comment: @MineR that's what i have been thinking as well. Usually the db connection that slows things down, but i have to make it so i was thinking of theres anything in the code i can correct.

Comment: @Questalot Some levels of Visual Studio do have a profiler, but that is not it. A profiler is a specific process where the code is run in a special mode / build, and the profiler tracks time spent in methods and modules. It generally even can highlight lines of code where a large amount of time is spent. Thus, you know what parts of the code take the longest. This means you then target those areas for performance improvement, then run the profiler again (and again...)

Comment: @AndrewMorton you are probably correct, i have moved that part down because i didn't want a db savechanges everytime i ran the inner loop, just when it finished the file should it save.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, i will try that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it takes minimum 20 minutes to run this, usually around 30 min minimum per file. Thats why i think it's slow. But as pointed out it's probably the actions towards the db that is slowing it down. I'm still a junior developer i guess so, im taking this as a lesson. Thank you all for your comments!

Answer (score -3):

You can always use Multi-Threading to make it possible on current computers.

You can use the Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach. this would improve speed drastically 
You just need to be careful on this example as it seems that order is important.

Bu the nature of Parallel it can access the array in any order so you will need to build something that takes this into consideration.

the other thing I would advise is to use two methods. one that reads the file

Comment: Thank you, I did use two methods at first. But when i was adding more things to go through i decided to have everything in one. But i prefer having methods that do one thing not several, so maybe i should take a look at that. Unsure if your proposal of Parallel.For and ForEach will help me in this case? Order is very important.

Comment: You can still maintain orders, just use an array to store the result using an indexer on the Parallel.For. something of the sort. `string[] lineArrays = new string[lines.Length];  Parallel.For(0, lines.Length, indexer => {
                    //do the transformation
                    lineArrays[indexer] = lines[indexer];

                });`

Comment: Okay, I will look into it and try it. Thank you